# Spring Security UI verify registration error

Tags: grails, spring-security

I get this error when I click verify registration that Spring Security UI plugin sent link to email.

```
Error 2013-07-20 01:12:14,684 [http-bio-8080-exec-6] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException occurred when processing request: [GET] /Professionals.az/register/verifyRegistration - parameters:
t: 4dc5d16cb60742809c7ef270f41cecdc
Duplicate entry '2-25' for key 'PRIMARY'. Stacktrace follows:
Message: Duplicate entry '2-25' for key 'PRIMARY'
    Line | Method
->>  411 | handleNewInstance    in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    386 | getInstance          in     ''
|   1039 | createSQLException . in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|   4096 | checkErrorPacket     in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   4028 | checkErrorPacket . . in     ''
|   2490 | sendCommand          in     ''
|   2651 | sqlQueryDirect . . . in     ''
|   2683 | execSQL              in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
|   2144 | executeInternal . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement
|   2444 | executeUpdate        in     ''
|   1997 | executeBatchSerially in     ''
|   1468 | executeBatch         in     ''
|    297 | executeBatch . . . . in org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement
|    687 | withTransaction      in org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi
|    158 | doCall . . . . . . . in az.com.controllers.register.RegisterController$_closure3$$EOC4Qhoo
|    195 | doFilter             in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter . . . . . . in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1110 | runWorker            in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run                  in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: it's there in your stacktrace - you're trying to insert the same data twice. Did you mean to do an update vs insert or is there some old data you haven't removed.

Comment: its happening here registrationCode.delete()

Comment: it happens during deletion

Comment: Show your controller and domain

Comment: RegistrationCode.withTransaction { status ->
   user = lookupUserClass().findByUsername(registrationCode.username)
   if (!user) {
    return
   }
   user.accountLocked = false
   user.save(flush:true)
   def UserRole = lookupUserRoleClass()
   def Role = lookupRoleClass()
   for (roleName in conf.ui.register.defaultRoleNames) {
    UserRole.create user, Role.findByAuthority(roleName)
   }
   registrationCode.delete()
  }

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same issue. What happened to me was that I already inserted the UserRole entry for the user that is trying to do the verification. Thus, resulting in the duplicate entry exception.

Try to check if you're not inserting entries that the controller also inserts into the database.